# select the max value of varchar in MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, subquery, max

I have an employee table and description table as given below.

***Employee table:***

```
empId    empName
================
 1       foo
 2       bar
```

***Description table:***

```
id  description empId
======================
1   test A      1
2   test B      1
3   test C      1
4   test D      2
5   test E      2
6   test F      1
```

I can join and get the latest description for each employee using something query as,

```
select e.empId, e.empName, d.description
from employee e
inner join description d on d.id=(select max(id) from description where empId=e.empId)
```

which will return the desired result as

```
empId        empName    description
===================================
1            foo        test F
2            bar        test E
```

But I like to know is there any other way to get the same result without subquery.

Comment: As per the chapter in the manual, you *can* do this without a subquery, but an uncorellated subquery solution will almost certainly be faster

Answer (score 0):

A solution involving a GROUP BY can be done, although it involves wrapping the original query in another select. It avoids the query to select the max id.

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT e.empId, e.empName, d.description
 FROM employee e
 JOIN description d USING (empId)
 ORDER BY e.empId ASC, d.id DESC
) tmp GROUP BY empId
```

Your original query can be performed using primary keys where this one involves temporary tables and probably a filesort so it may not be as performant.

Comment: This is an undocumented solution, a 'hack' if you like. But hey, hacks can be fun.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this without subquery, but you can rewrite as:

```
select e.empId,
       e.empName,
       (select description from description 
        where empId = e.empId 
        order by id desc limit 1) as description
from employee e
```

Comment: Yes.. But there are more than five tables to be merged so me guess join query is better for higher performance

Comment: In your question you have 2 tables. How could I know about 5 tables. You should run both queries and see which is better. No one will tell you unlees you measure both.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT e.empId, e.empName, d.description
FROM employee e
JOIN description d USING (empId)
join (
    SELECT MAX(d.id) as id
    FROM description d
    GROUP BY d.empId
) AS maxd ON maxd.id = d.id
```